# selecting the highest count for a categorical variable when grouping

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following table:

```
custID  Cat
   1    A
   1    B
   1    B
   1    B
   1    C
   2    A
   2    A
   2    C
   3    B
   3    C
   4    A
   4    C
   4    C
   4    C
```

What I need is the most efficient way to aggregate by CustID in such a manner that I obtain the most frequent category (cat), the second most frequent and the third. The output of the above should be

```
    most freq   2nd most freq   3rd most freq
1       B             A              C
2       A             C             Null
3       B             C             Null
4       C             A             Null
```

When there is a tie in the count I do not really care what is first and what is second. For example for customer 1 2nd most freq and 3rd most freq could be swapped because each of them occur 1 time only.

Any sql would be fine, preferable hive sql.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `group by` twice and `dense_rank()` to sort accorting to the `cat` count. Actually I'm not 100% sure , but I guess it should work in hive as well.

```
select custId,
    max(case when t.rn = 1 then cat end) as [most freq],
    max(case when t.rn = 2 then cat end) as [2nd most freq],
    max(case when t.rn = 3 then cat end) as [3th most freq]
from
(
  select custId, cat, dense_rank() over (partition by custId order by count(*) desc) rn
  from your_table 
  group by custId, cat
) t
group by custId
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=afb99883cd120d366675f22f9806dc7c)

According to the comments I add slightly modified solution that conforms with Hive SQL

```
select custId,
    max(case when t.rn = 1 then cat else null end) as most_freq,
    max(case when t.rn = 2 then cat else null end) as 2nd_most_freq,
    max(case when t.rn = 3 then cat else null end) as 3th_most_freq
from
(
  select custId, cat, dense_rank() over (partition by custId order by ct desc) rn
  from (
    select custId, cat, count(*) ct
    from your_table 
    group by custId, cat
  ) your_table_with_counts
) t
group by custId
```

[Hive SQL demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a6a7d9b42c3e00fae724945746992338)

Comment: use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number` so that ties don't show up in 2nd and 3rd most frequent values in case they exist.

Comment: also remove `[]` for column-aliases as they are not supported in Hive.

Comment: I ran it but I got this error: 
"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 7:84 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count' ". 
Could be hive sql problem. The issue becomes purely technical. I think you have solved it in terms of data logic for which I am thankful to the both of you.

Comment: @criticalth ok and when you try this? http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a6a7d9b42c3e00fae724945746992338

Comment: @RadimBača I do not understand what table is supposed to be your_table_with_counts

Comment: @criticalth it is not a table it is a named result of the SQL subquery

Comment: @RadimBača it is running ... will get back soon

Comment: @RadimBača It worked perfectly. Could you just enter the code from your comment (i mean the link that you provided) in the solution comment and I will accept it ? They are a bit different. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT journal, count(*) as frequency
FROM ${hiveconf:TNHIVE}
WHERE journal IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY journal
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: @PouriaHemati’s point is especially important here, where there’s already a high-quality accepted answer. Under what conditions is your approach an improvement? Why should readers adopt your approach?